# How can I make an excel spreadsheet log that will put multiple entries under one record

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2016

So I'm fairly new-ish to excel and I'm making a log to track our purchase orders. My issue is I can't figure a way to enter them in without merging rows; for example purchase order #5 will have 1 item in it but purchase order #6 will have 10.

I've thought about making a separate table that would populate a presenting table but again, I don't know how to make it organized and usuable.

Is there a clean and organized way to enter in multiple items under one entry without creating some Frankenstein excel sheet that's impossible to sort and filter through? Should I switch to a database software like Access or is there some cool excel trick I'm not seeing?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Have you thought about using a Pivot Table?

Comment: Have you thought about using a database, such as MySQL?

Answer (score 1):

Your dilemna about organising your data is a common one. In essence, you have two types of data: the first type is the purchase order, whilst the second is the purchase lines within each purchase order.

Purchase order data might typically include information like:

- Purchase order number
- Supplier
- Date raised
- Approver
- Status (Such as waiting to be sent to supplier, waiting for goods to be received,  all goods received, matched to supplier invoice, etc)

Purchase lines data might typically include

- Purchase order number
- Line number within the purchase order
- Ordered item code number
- Unit price
- Ordered quantity
- Date goods received

As you have found sometimes a Purchase Order contains only one Purchase Line but sometimes a Purchase Order may have multiple lines. That is the root of your dilemna.

Dependent on what you want to get out of your tracking log (ie the business purposes is it intended to serve) you may need both types of data. If you are only interested  in say the financial value  of goods on order, then you may only need the second type of data. Generally, though, both types of data will be useful to have and will help maximise the value of your tracking log.

An ideal solution would involve use of database software - the two data types will correspond to tables in the database and can be "linked" (related) together via the purchase order number which is common to both types of data. But if you only have a couple of tables (as in this case), you can achieve a fair amount using Excel.

In Excel, you can use functions like `=COUNTIFS()`, `=SUMIFS()`, `=VLOOKUP`, `INDEX/MATCH` to "hack" the type of processing that would be undertaken using SQL in a database environment. Be careful and make sure your data is consistent both between and within the two types of data (no mispellings, extra inserted spaces in names, etc). You will undoubtedly come to regret any inconsistencies as the amount of data in your tracking log grows - results will be incorrect and errors hard to find.

Have a close look at what was being said nearly 12 years ago in [this question and answer](https://superuser.com/questions/119087/how-best-to-manage-my-growing-data-in-excel). The first answer is particularly relevant.

Avoid confusing data with presentation of results of that data (or even presentation of the data itself). I touched on this theme in an earlier answer to [another question](https://superuser.com/questions/1695241/excel-how-to-bind-group-several-data-points-to-one-so-that-if-the-arrangement-i/1695293#1695293). There is also some helpful advice about some of the principles of basic data management on [this page](https://www.pryor.com/blog/tips-for-data-management-in-excel/).

Answer (score 0):

You will need to create a VBA code that will allow you multiple selections in a drop down for one purchase order. You can find all the instructions here: https://trumpexcel.com/select-multiple-items-drop-down-list-excel/
Make sure to follow the one that has "with repetition" in the title.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: You could do it this way, but in effect, it will mangle the data horribly. It mixes organisation of data with presentation. How could you easily determine from such comma separated entries how many purchase orders have been placed have been placed for a particular item, or the average number of such items placed per purchase order? If the data is stored as a list then the OP can process the list to present the data as you are suggesting (if that is a requirement) without compromising the ability to do useful analysis and monitoring of the purchase orders.